# implement a simple counter to count reactive firing in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I would like to keep track of how many times the user has refreshed my Shiny vis.

I figured I would just set a counter up outside of the reactive area

`number <- 0`

and have it update by adding one every time the code in reactive block fires.

But it doesn't work.

Ideas:

<del>make the counter a global var?</del>
silly idea, doesn't work
   <del>put the `number <- 0` inside the reactive area?</del>
of
   course that's not the solution

I'm not sure which direction to go here. Anyone have any ideas?

```
require(shiny)
number <- 0
runApp(list(ui = pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("This is a test"),
  sidebarPanel(
    helpText("This is a test"),

    sliderInput("range",
                label = "Pick a number:",
                min = 0, max = 100, value = 0)
  ),
  mainPanel(textOutput("text1"),
            htmlOutput("text")
  )
),
server = function(input, output) {
  number <- number + 1
  output$text <- renderUI({
    str <- paste("You have chosen:",
                 input$range)
    HTML(paste(str, sep = '<br/>'))
  View(number)
  })
}
)
)
```

Answer (score 4):

Shiny has `reactiveValues` that are like an environment - they get passed by reference so you can assign to them with the regular assignment operator from within reactive expressions.  For example,

```
library(shiny)
ui <- pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("This is a test"),
  sidebarPanel(sliderInput("range", "Pick", 0, 100, 10)),
  mainPanel(htmlOutput("text"))
)

server <- function(session, input, output) {
  vals <- reactiveValues(count = -1)
  observeEvent(input$range, vals$count <- vals$count + 1)

  output$text <- renderUI({
    HTML(paste(sprintf("You have chosen: %s</br>", vals$count)))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Sidenote: you could also do it as a global variable like mentioned using `<<-`, but I would say it is a bad idea because of how `<<-` searches backwards through environments, and I think that it could have surprising results.

Comment: what do you mean by 'searches backwards'?

Comment: @MonicaHeddneck "upwards" is probably better description, but it seeks successively through parent environments, and if it doesn't find the symbol it assigns it in the last environment.  As you can imagine it is generally avoided.

Comment: Just an upvote for using reactiveValues and voicing another opinion that says do not use <<-