# plot_ly() and shiny: change transparency of area fill in interactive environment

Tags: r, shiny, plotly

What I want to achieve:
A line plot with filled area below the lines. The line (or marker) opacity should be 1, the opacity of fillcolor should be around 0.1, since 3 to 10 traces will end up in the same plot.

I'm still quite new to plot_ly, so it might be I'm missing something obvious. However, I'm aware of the fillcolor argument letting me specifiy rgba-colors. I further vaguely understand the potential of layout.colorway to get matching fillcolors.
I'd love to see a solution that doesn't require manual adjustment, since the traces are added interactively inside a shiny app.
Below is a toy example of what I'd like to have as a result. The for-loop knows how many traces there are already in the plot, but this is an information the interactive function does not have. How can I bypass this (preferably without adding a counter inside the shiny app)?

Thanks for any suggestions!

```
library(plotly)
dat <- list(x =c(1,2,3),
            y1=c(3,5,6),
            y2=c(7,1,3),
            y3=c(1,4,7)
       )
## default colors of layout.colorway
pltColors  <- c("#1f77b4", "#ff7f0e", "#2ca02c", "#d62728", "#9467bd",
                "#8c564b", "#e377c2", "#7f7f7f", "#bcbd22", "#17becf")
## make them tranparent
pltColorsA <- paste0(pltColors,"20")


plt <- plot_ly(df, type="scatter", mode='lines+markers',
               x=~x, y=~y1,
               span=5,
               fill='tozeroy',
               fillcolor=pltColorsA[1])
for(i in 2:4){
  yi <- df[,i]
  plt <-  add_trace(plt,data=df, x=~x, y=yi,
                           fill='tozeroy',
                           fillcolor=pltColorsA[i])
}
plt
```

**EDIT**
Here is a minimal example of a shiny app. The user adds traces by klicking an actionButton. The default transparency of 0.5 of the area fill makes the plot look cluttered after a few traces, so I'd like to set the tranparency to roughly 0.1 as in the plot above. I don't know how to achieve this since the add_trace() doesn't know (and does not need to know) anything about past traces.

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
if (interactive()) {

ui <- fluidPage(
    actionButton('addTrace','Klick Me to add a trace!'),
    plotlyOutput('plt')
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  plt  <- plot_ly(type="scatter",
                  mode="lines+markers",
                  fill="tozeroy",
                  span=I(5))
  reac <- reactiveValues(plotlyObj = plt)

  observeEvent(input$addTrace,
      reac$plotlyObj <- add_trace(reac$plotlyObj, x=1:4, y=sample(1:10,4))
  )
  output$plt <- renderPlotly(reac$plotlyObj)

}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you clarified what you are trying to achive, maybe this will fit your needs. Following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36229674/implement-a-simple-counter-to-count-reactive-firing-in-shiny) I added a counter to your shiny app which keeps track of the traces and picks the colors accordingsly. After 10 traces  the colors are recycled.

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
if (interactive()) {
  
  pltColors  <- c("#1f77b4", "#ff7f0e", "#2ca02c", "#d62728", "#9467bd",
                  "#8c564b", "#e377c2", "#7f7f7f", "#bcbd22", "#17becf")
  ## make them tranparent
  pltColorsA <- paste0(pltColors,"1A")
  
  ui <- fluidPage(
    actionButton('addTrace','Klick Me to add a trace!'),
    plotlyOutput('plt')
  )
  
  server <- function(input, output) {
    plt  <- plot_ly(type="scatter",
                    mode="lines+markers",
                    fill="tozeroy",
                    span=I(5))
    reac <- reactiveValues(plotlyObj = plt)
    
    vals <- reactiveValues(counter = 0)
    
    observeEvent(input$addTrace, {
      vals$counter <- vals$counter + 1
      message(glue::glue("Counter: {vals$counter}"))
      reac$plotlyObj <- add_trace(reac$plotlyObj, 
                                  x=1:4, 
                                  y=sample(1:10,4),
                                  color = I(pltColors[(vals$counter - 1) %% 10 + 1]),
                                  fillcolor = pltColorsA[(vals$counter - 1) %% 10 + 1])
    })
    
    output$plt <- renderPlotly(reac$plotlyObj)
    
  }
  shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the clean code! But it still relies on a for loop with a counting variable, which I wanted to get rid of. I added an shiny example above to clarify what I want to achieve.

Comment: Okay. I see. Wasn't clear to me what you are trying to achieve. Best

Comment: Hi @new_here_hi_everyone. I just edited and revised my code. Maybe this fits your needs. Best

Comment: thanks again!

While trying to clarify my question, I had the idea to look deeper into the structure of the plotly class.  
`length(<plotly.object>$x$attrs)` gives the number of traces currently in the plot. Thus I can prevent the use of additional counters, which would be my preferred solution. I'll still accept your answer, since (a) it answers the question and (b) helped me a lot. 
Thanks again, bye!